# is there a sample rails application that uses a "sign on with google" approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api

is there a sample rails application that uses a "sign on with google" approach?  ideally using the most popular library/gem for underlying assistance (e.g. OpenID / OAuth etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [omniauth gem for google (oauth2)](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) there are some examples and in the general [omniauth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki) there is great documentation on how to proceed

Comment: thanks - do you happen to know how this compares to the oauth gem & oauth plugin I've been trying so far, which I'm using for getting google calendar data.  Are they actually two totally separate things, i.e. separate gems/approaches for doing the "sign in via google" as opposed to "access google calendar data via their api"?

Comment: PS. Starting to see that "sign in via google" seems to need OpenID, whereas accessing data via google api needs OAuth..(?)